# Packet Tracer HTTPS protocol

Tags: packet

When I enter IP address of WLC-1 from the addressing table into the address bar, 192.168.200.254. I get a message for Server Reset Connection. Can someone help me on how to solve this issue?

I was expecting to get a login page to see the WLC Monitor Summary screen.